# Send state of a QCheckBox and a number when clicked

Tags: python, pyqt5, signals-slots, qcheckbox

I'm trying to pass two separate variables via a `QCheckBox` clicked signal: its post-pressed state, and its index in the list.

For example, this is my code:

```py
# pip install pyqt5
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *
from functools import partial
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5 import *
import sys
batch_name = ['Test1', 'test2', 'test']
total_batches = 0
unfinished_batches = 0
class MainMenu(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        global total_batches, unfinished_batches, batch_name
        super(MainMenu, self).__init__(parent)
        self.scroll = QScrollArea(self)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.content = QWidget()
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.content)
        self.lay = QGridLayout(self.content)
        for i, j in enumerate(batch_name):
            self.btnName = QPushButton(j, self)
            self.btnName.setFlat(True)
            self.lay.addWidget(self.btnName, i, 1)
            self.check_box = QCheckBox(self)
            checkbox_index = partial(self.clickBox, i, i)
            self.check_box.stateChanged.connect(checkbox_index)
            self.lay.addWidget(self.check_box, i, 0)
            total_batches += 1
    def clickBox(self, state, index):
        print(index)
        print(state)
        global unfinished_batches, total_batches
        if state == Qt.Checked:
            unfinished_batches += 1
        else:
            unfinished_batches -= 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainMenu()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

(Yes, I know I'm passing the index threw twice.)

So lets say, I press the first `QCheckBox` (`Test1`): I should get `True` for the state, and `0` for the index. If I press `Test1` again, I expect to get `False` for the state, and again `0` for the index. For just one more example, if I press `test` (last `QCheckBox`) I should expect to get `True` for the state, and `2` for the index, and pressing it again, I should get `False` for the state, and again, `2` for the index.

The code above gives me the index, but it doesn't give me its state - that's what I'm stuck on. What I am expecting to happen if the `QCheckBox` is pressed then I should get `True` where I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from functools import partial
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class MainMenu(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainMenu, self).__init__(parent)

        batch_name = ['Test1', 'test2', 'test']
        lay = QGridLayout(self)

        for i, j in enumerate(batch_name):
            check_box = QCheckBox()
            lay.addWidget(check_box, i, 0)

            btnName = QPushButton(j)
            btnName.setFlat(True)
            btnName.setCheckable(True)
            btnName.clicked.connect(partial(self.btnCliced, i, j, check_box))
            lay.addWidget(btnName, i, 1)

            check_box.stateChanged.connect(partial(self.clickBox, i, j, btnName))            

    def clickBox(self, i, j, btnName, state):             
        print(f'clickBox:  i={i}, j={j}, state={state} : {bool(state)};')
        if state: btnName.setChecked(True)
        else: btnName.setChecked(False)

    def btnCliced(self, i, j, check_box, state):             
        print(f'btnCliced: i={i}, j={j}, state={state};')
        if state: check_box.setChecked(True)
        else: check_box.setChecked(False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainMenu()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: This works wonderfully well too!!! Wow! Thank you so much for this!

This would work better for me, even tho I had a different solution in mind, but this makes it easier, as I get the name that its corresponding to! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're not using `partial` correctly. If both parameters are specified in `partial`, then both the arguments of `clickBox` will be overwritten with the value of `i`. What you need to do is only specify the value of the `index` argument, and allow the signal to supply the value of the `state` argument. This can be done using a keyword argument, like this:

```
    # checkbox_index = partial(self.clickBox, i, i)
    checkbox_index = partial(self.clickBox, index=i)
```

But note that `state` will be a value from the [CheckState enum](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#CheckState-enum), so if you specifically want to get `True/False`, you could use a `lambda` instead:

```
    checkbox_index = lambda state, index=i: self.clickBox(state == Qt.Checked, index)
```

and `clickState` would need to look like this:

```
def clickBox(self, state, index):
    print(index)
    print(state)
    global unfinished_batches, total_batches
    if state == True:
        unfinished_batches += 1
    else:
        unfinished_batches -= 1
```

Comment: This does work, Not as I expected, but I can work with this I think. Thank you very much!

Comment: @JareBear What were you expecting?

Comment: A `True` or `False` value, it would make sense if it would, but its no big deal.

Comment: @JareBear I have added another solution that does that.

Comment: It didn't work for me.. But it doesn't matter, the first solution worked.

Comment: @JareBear What didn't work? I tested it with your code, and it does exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Well, assuming this is how you set it up:
`checkbox_index = lambda state, index=i: self.clickBox(state == Qt.Checked, index)
self.check_box.stateChanged.connect(checkbox_index)`

it doesn't take away the `unfinished_batches` number when its un-checked

Comment: @JareBear That's probably because you are still using `if state == Qt.Checked:` in `clickBox`. You need to use `if state == True:` instead.

Comment: Ah!!! yes, that was the problem.. That now works perfectly! Thank you so much!